# Replacement for VS + Resharper

Tags: visual-studio, ide, resharper, visual-studio-macros, context-sensitive-help

I'm a long time c# dev, who are currently looking into possibly expanding to java, or typescript.

I am currently relying a lot on the efficiency of resharper/VS to do a lot of manual things for me, such as:

- Ctrl + t to search for file/class/method
- Macros (typing "class" + tab for a complete class structure for instance)
- Ctrl +r,r to rename and rename all references
- Auto suggestions for variable names depending on context
- Context sensitive ctrl + . which allows me to:

  - Format variable names according to configurable coding standards
  - Mark members as readonly whenever possible
  - Auto create/assign member from a typed in constructor parameter
  - Move a class/struct to it's own file
  - write for instance "int x = myclassInstance.NonexistingMethod();" and then automatically create that method, with the right return value, using ctrl + .

This is just a part of my most used features. My question is: what other IDE's (for java or typescript preferably) give me the same tooling?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) and [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). Both are by JetBrains, who make ReSharper. They should be able to do all of the things you're asking for, and have trial versions on the website. Note that IntelliJ Ultimate is a superset of all of the other IDEs, so includes all of WebStorm's tooling.

Comment: They also have a new one called Rider. It is supposed to do C# and JavaScript and Typescript.  (I am looking into something like this too.). Rider is still very new.

Comment: Yes, [Rider](https://jetbrains.com/rider/) uses ReSharper's engine to provide C# functionality, and WebStorm's engine to provide TypeScript and JavaScript support.